# web2py: Replace Smartgrid standard delete button

Tags: python, web2py

I wanted to replace the standard delete button in Smartgrid. Here's what I attempted to do:

```
def list_service_types():
    grid = SQLFORM.smartgrid(db.service_types
        , fields = [db.service_types.type_name, db.services.service_name]
        , ondelete = ondelete_service_type
        , links = [lambda row: A('Delete', _href='#', _glyph="icon-trash", _class="button btn btn-secondary", )]
        )
    return locals()
```

Problems:

1) I can't get the icon-trash glyph/icon to display 
2) How do I position the new button at the end of the row, eventually replacing the standard delete button

Screen shot follows:
[image: Screenshot]

**Edit 1**
I managed to make the glyph show with the following `links`:

```
    , links = [lambda row: A('Delete', _href='#', _class="button btn btn-secondary icon trash icon-trash glyphicon glyphicon-trash", )]
```

but the font and spacing are off. I can see from the page source that `<span>` tags must be in place, like the following:

```
<span class="icon trash icon-trash glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
```

but I dont know how to proceed.

Screenshot follows:
[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Assuming you're still interested in a solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54175545/440323), check out the [updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54200430/440323), which includes a solution that works for grids in Ajax components.

Comment: Regarding this question, there is no simple way to move your custom `links` relative to the built-in buttons. You would have to do it via manipulation of the [server-side DOM](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/05/the-views#Server-side-DOM-and-parsing), custom CSS, or custom Javascript.

Comment: Out of my league for now